# What's wrong here using 'Object' as a substitute for specific type?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-programming

I wrote some code to test `Supplier` and something went wrong but I don't know why.

here is the code:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 11).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<User> newList = addToList(list, User::new);
        System.out.println(newList);
    }

    private static <T extends User> List<T> addToList(List<Object> srcList, Supplier<T> sp) {
        if (srcList == null || srcList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return srcList.stream().map(src -> {
            T t = sp.get();
            t.setAge(Integer.parseInt(src.toString()));
            return t;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static class User {
        Integer age;

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

`List<User> newList = addToList(list, User::new)` it has an error here says:
**"Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert User to T".**

Then I change the private method to below:

```java
    private static <T extends User, R> List<T> addToList(List<R> srcList, Supplier<T> sp) {
        if (srcList == null || srcList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return srcList.stream().map(src -> {
            T t = sp.get();
            t.setAge(Integer.parseInt(src.toString()));
            return t;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

and there is no error this time.

What's happened here? Every class should be the subclass of `Object`, buy why can't I use 'Object' here?

I would appreciate it if someone help me.

Comment: `List<Integer>` cannot be used where `List<Object>` is expected. `Integer` is an `Object`, but `List<Integer>` is *not* a `List<Object>`

Comment: For more info check this doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html